# How do I create a functional test which includes a POST to a page with parameters?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I've read the documentation from Symfony2 but it doesn't seem to work.  Here's my functional test:

```
public function testSearch()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('POST', '/search/results', array('term' => 'Carteron'));
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("Carteron")')->count() > 0);
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("Auctions")')->count() > 0);
}
```

In my controller the "term" parameter is null when this request comes in.  However, search works just fine when I perform it on the site, so I know its a problem with setting up the test.

Comment: How does your action look like?

Comment: `public function searchResultsAction()
{
 $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
 $term=$request->request->get('term');
 $logger = $this->get("logger");
 $logger->debug("Search term $term");
 if(strlen($term)==0)
 {
  $this->get('session')->setFlash('notice', "A search string must be longer than nothing!! :P");
  return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_welcome'));
 }
      //search code here (removed due to post length restrictions)
}`

But like I mentioned, this works fine when I search manually

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, neither `$request->query` nor `$request->request` worked. Both did the same for me: it returned `$default`, not the given `$parameters` (Symfony 2.3).

Same behaviour as chris, in normal web browsers it works. I fixed this by replacing:

```
public function searchResultsAction($name)
{
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $term = trim($request->request->get('term'));
    return $this->searchResultsWithTermAction($term);
}
```

With:

```
public function searchResultsAction(Request $request, $name)
{
    // do NOT overwrite $request, we got it as parameter
    //$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $term = trim($request->request->get('term'));
    return $this->searchResultsWithTermAction($term);
}
```

So `createFromGlobals()` does only work if `$_GET` and `$_POST` are set. Shich is not the case if you use the symfony test client. you have to add the `$request` parameter to the action.

(I used `$name` as a GET parameter in my routing)

Answer (score 0):

I've never gotten an answer to this, but have implemented a work around that seems to work for my testing purposes.  I'd love to hear feedback or get a real answers to this questions.

What I've done is create a 2nd route for the purposes of testing.

In real usage the uri would be `/search/results?term=searchtermhere`

For the purposes of testing, this didn't work.  I could never get access to the term value when invoked via the automated test.
So what I've done is create a 2nd route just for testing which has a uri of `/search/results/{searchtermhere}`.

Then my action class used for a real search would call down to another function and pass the term to the function:

```
public function searchResultsAction()
{
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $term = trim($request->request->get('term'));
    return $this->searchResultsWithTermAction($term);
}
```

So my functional tests would excersize `searchResultsWithTermAction()`, so the only code coverage I'm missing from this workaround is the extraction of the term from the request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone is still searching for an answer to this, but basically the problem is that you are looking in the wrong place for the parameter.

For your example you would need:

```
$term = trim($request->query->get('term'));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll give this a try... but why would what I have work for regular web browser requests, but not the browser kit built into the functional tests?

Comment: Sorry, it was meant as a replacement for the equivalent line of code, but I missed the LHS out. I have put it in with my edit so that it might make more sense