# Symfony2 Functional test: Passing form data directly

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I am using phpunit to run functional tests but I am having a problem with a few of the forms. The problem is that phpunit is not aware of JS, and I have a form with a dynamically populated select box that needs jQuery.

So I need to pass the form data directly. The 'book' gives the following example:

```
// Directly submit a form (but using the Crawler is easier!)
$client->request('POST', '/submit', array('name' => 'Fabien'));
```

When I used this example the controller didn't receive any of the form data. Intially I saw that passing the array key 'name' wasn't correct in my situation as I needed the form name which was 'timesheet' in my code. So I tried something like:

```
$client->request('POST', '/timesheet/create', array('timesheet[project]' => '100'));
```

But this still didn't work. In the controller I tried to understand what was happening and what if anything was being received:

```
$postData = $request->request->get('timesheet');
$project = $postData['project'];
```

This didn't work and $project remained empty. However if I used the following code I got the value:

```
$project = $request->request->get('timesheet[project]');
```

But clearly that's not what I want. Atleast though I can see that there is some POST data. My last attempt was to try the following in the test method:

```
$this->crawler = $this->client->request('POST', '/timesheet/create/', array('timesheet' => array(project => '100'));
```

So I am trying to pass a 'timesheet' array as the first element of the request parameter array. But with this I get the error:

```
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException: Expected argument of type "array", "string" given (uncaught exception) at /mnt/hgfs/pmt/src/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 489
```

I would be very happy if someone can expand on what's in the 'book' about how I am supposed to get this working.

Form bind in controller:

```
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $postData = $request->request->get('timesheet');
            $project = $postData['project'];                             

            $timesheetmanager = $this->get('wlp_pmt.timesheet_db_access');
            $timesheetmanager->editTimesheet($timesheet);                                               
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('timesheet_list'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your last try looks fine to me. Please paste part of your controller where you bind the form.

Also, did you read the documentation chapter on functional testing (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/testing.html#forms)? You might try manipulating the form element.

Comment: I've added the relevant controller part now. I've read through the chapter in the book concerning functional testing a few times now looking for anything I may have missed. When you suggest to manipulate the form element, do you mean to add the data in the functional test to the form? This isn't possible as the form has a dynamic selection that's populated using AJAX. So it's empty and nothing can be selected, hence I need to POST the form contents to the controller.

Answer (score 5):

If you are wanting to know how to inject arrays of POST data using the test client...

In your test method, do something like

```
$crawler = $client->request('POST', '/foo', array(
    'animal_sounds' => array(
        'cow'  => 'moo',
        'duck' => 'quack'
    )
); // This would encode to '/foo?animal_sounds%5Bcow%5D=moo&animal_sounds%5Bduck%5D=quack'

$this->assertTrue( ... );
```

In the controller, you would access your params like this:

```
$data = $request->request->get('animal_sounds');
$cowNoise = $data['cow'];
$duckNoise = $data['duck'];
```

Or you could just use the forms API if the test method was injecting valid form data...

Comment: If this answers your question could you mark it as correct? If it doesn't could you add a comment explaining why? Thanks!

Comment: i test it, and it didn't work. I don't know why. When i test directly using REST debug. It work :|. Seems like Symfony WebTestCase bugs :|

Comment: oddly enough, after hours of searching, this is the ONLY Place on the internet in can find out definitively that the 3rd parameter is where the post data goes.  Thank you for this..  If somebody can provide a better link where it states what each param is for then im all ears.

Answer (score 2):

do you have a `$request` parameter in your action?
that was the reason why my `request->get()` was empty:

```
//WRONG
public function projectAction()
{
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $project = $request->request->get('timesheet[project]');
    //$project will be empty
}


//CORRECT
public function projectAction(Request $request)
{
    $project = $request->request->get('timesheet[project]');
    //$project is not empty
}
```

see
[How do I create a functional test which includes a POST to a page with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439782/how-do-i-create-a-functional-test-which-includes-a-post-to-a-page-with-parameter/24929517#24929517)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$form->bind($clientData)` instead of `$form->bindRequest($request)`.